# Función para recargar cualquier región de la vista, pasando id como parametro

Tags: jquery, ajax

actualmente tengo la siguiente función asociada al evento `‘click’` de una etiqueta `<a>` con `id="lnkRecargaRegistros"`, esta función siempre que se utiliza actualiza el `tbody`  de una tabla con `id="tablaDatos"`, con el contenido del recurso `href`  de la etiqueta `<a>`.
Para usarla en una vista, incluyo una etiqueta `<a>` de la siguiente manera:

```
<a id="lnkRecargaRegistros" href="{{ path('embarazada_recargarListadoNodo', {'nodoId':estructuraOrganizativa.id}) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a>
```

Este es el handler del evento click:

```
$('#vistas').on('click', '#lnkRecargaRegistros', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        'datatypes': 'html',
        'type': 'GET',
        'url': url,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#indicador').addClass('cargando-satisfactorio').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#tablaDatos tbody').html(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
        $('#indicador').removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').addClass('cargando-error').html(jqXHR.responseText);
    }).always(function(jqXHR, status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            $('#indicador').fadeOut(5500, function() {
                $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
            });
        } else {
            $('#indicador').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

De esta forma funciona perfecto para recargar el `tbody` de la tabla con `id="tablaDatos"`.
Ahora bien, para recargar el contenido de una vista completa he tenido que implementar otro handler muy similar al anterior, con la única diferencia que en el `.done` de la llamada AJAX,   simplemente he cambiado el id del elemento a actualizar.

Y cada vez que necesito actualizar una vista completa utilizo entonces una etiqueta `<a>` pero con `id="lnkCargarVista"`

Mi duda es como hacer un handler genérico para el evento `´click´` de una etiqueta `<a>` de manera tal que me recargue un elemento pasado por parámetro  o establecido como atributo de la etiqueta.
Es que necesito que mi fichero de scripts.js sea lo más mínimo posible y básicamente estoy repitiendo código para hacer casi lo mismo, actualizar un determinada región de la página.

Comment: Si gran parte del código se repite, es que una función puede resultar bastante útil.

Comment: @Cheshire, no entiendo, pudiera crear una función con toda la lógica del handler, y bindearla al evento click, peeero de dónde tomo el id del elemento que deseo actualizar con la respuesta del servidor ???.

Comment: JQuery permite coger todos los atributos de un elemento. Dependiendo del id del elemento clicados, puedes hacer que la respuesta del ajax haga una cosa u otra cuando tengas que actualizar

Answer (score 0):

No conozco tu HTML, pero si ambos link (a) están en la misma vista podés cambiar el selector #lnkRecargaRegistros para que tome ambos links, una vez hecho esto el código es igual según comentás, lo único que cambia es el selector dentro del .done, bien acá podes hacer algo simple: agregar un atributo a cada link (#lnkRecargaRegistros y el otro) algo como  y lo lees desde tu código $(this).attr("data-objetivo") y listo.
Sin probar el código quedaría más o menos así

```
$('#vistas').on('click', '#lnkRecargaRegistros #otroLink', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$.ajax({
    'datatypes': 'html',
    'type': 'GET',
    'url': url,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#indicador').addClass('cargando-satisfactorio').fadeIn('fast');
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    var tabla = $(this).attr("data-objetivo");
    $('#' + table + ' tbody').html(data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR) {
    $('#indicador').removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').addClass('cargando-error').html(jqXHR.responseText);
}).always(function(jqXHR, status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        $('#indicador').fadeOut(5500, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
        });
    } else {
        $('#indicador').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
        });
    }
});
```

});

el HTML sería: 
`<a id="lnkRecargaRegistros" data-objetivo="tablaDatos">`